# Can I have different name and id attributes on a form element?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web form with usual elements (first name, last name, etc).  The Postback URL is a different website altogether as the form is intented to post lead information to another website.

The site that accepts the lead is expecting First Name to come over as "FName", and Last Name to come over as "LName".  Is there any way I can set the ID of a textbox to "txtFName", but submit it over the wire as "FName"?  I tried changing the name attribute, but at runtime it sets the name = id.

Answer (score 2):

You should use normal (non-`runat="server"`) `<input>` elements.
You will then have complete control over the name and id.

Comment: Sorry SLaks, but this doesnt help, I need runat=server on the control because on page load I may be writing to the field as well.  Its very possible I cant have my cake and eat it too... but thats why I thought Id check on SO first ;)

Comment: @ewitkows: You can set the element's properties using `<%=...%>`, without `runat="server"`.  (Just remember to encode the data)

Answer (score 0):

for 'standard-html-input-elements', the name attribute, is the one being submitted, the id-attribute may be used e.g. in javascript.

Comment: Sorry Gerhard, but thats not the case.  If I specify name as "z" and id as "abc", on page load name AND id are both "abc"/